# Prove if $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, such that $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$, and $m,n ∈\mathbb{ N}$, with $m ≥ n$. Then $x^m ≤ x^n$

Tags: real-numbers

How to prove the following prop.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $0 \le x \le 1$, and $m,n \in\mathbb{ N}$, with $m \ge n$. Then $x^m \le x^n$.

I don't exactly know where to begin with this proof, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: If $0 \le a \le b$, and $0 \le c$, then $ac \le bc$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 \leq x^m = x^n\cdot x^{m-n} \leq x^n\cdot 1 = x^n$

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: $x^{m-n} \leq 1$ since $0 \leq x \leq 1$, and $m-n \geq 0$.

Comment: how do we get to x^m > x^n though?

Comment: I just corrected the edit that was done earlier. Its $x^m \leq x^n$

Comment: makes much more sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=m-n$. If $d=0$, there is nothing to prove. If $d>0$, we have
$$
x^m-x^n=x^n(x^d-1)=\underbrace{x^n}_{\ge 0}\underbrace{(x-1)}_{\le 0}\underbrace{(x^{d-1}+\cdots+x+1)}_{\ge 1}\leq 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $0\leq x\leq 1$ then $xB\leq B$ for any positive $B$.